# In eclipse rcp adding a new gef figure doesn't invoke selection change

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am building an eclipse rcp application with the compatability layer (between version 3 and 4).

I am using GEF 3. Now when I create a new GEF figure the `SelectionService` of eclipse doesn't invoke `handleSelectionChanged()` method for some reason. The resulting bug is that actions that are supposed to be enabled due to the selection change are not enabled.

By the way, the figure appears to be selected in the GUI. The only way to invoke the selection change is to click on another GUI element and then to click back on the figure. Meaning that GEF thinks that the figure is selected.

Any ideas??

Comment: This is a tough one .. wish i had an answer :)

Comment: Have your tried firing a selection changed event programmatically? E.g., in the `activate()` method in the `EditPart`?

Comment: this didn't work :-(.

Comment: There's an article that suggests that you can suppress events by consuming them. For example in a mouselistener https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/368009/. You might want to check that.